# JNI local ref lifetime in a JVM host app

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface

The JNI docs state that local Java object references are in scope until the native method returns; also that they're local to the thread.

When an application hosts a Java VM, Java object references might be created outside of any native method. Once a JVM is running, the host app may obtain a `JNIEnv` and create Java objects all it wants. One assumes this scenario produces local refs.

What's the lifetime of those, please? Do they live as long as the JVM lives (unless freed explicitly)? Are they thread local too? If on a worker thread, do they go out of scope once the thread is detached from a JVM?

Specifically about thread locality: so far, reusing class objects (as returned from `FindClass()`) between threads would work as expected for me. But is that a violation of JNI rules?

Comment: No need to assume. The JNI Specification says 'All Java objects returned by JNI functions are local references.' It also says you may not pass local references from one native thread to another. Given  both these statements it is unclear what your difficulty is.

Comment: How come I'm consistently getting away with it when it comes to class objects?

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev By a lucky chance. E.g. Class instances being long-lived objects tend to fall to Old Generation where they rarely move. However, this is absolutely not guaranteed. Once a Class instance is relocated in Heap, an access to invalid `jclass` local reference may cause JVM crash.

Comment: Because you got lucky. You can't rely on luck. You can rely on the specification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A valid `JNIEnv` that can be used to create local references may be obtained through:

1. A native method call. Local references will be valid until the method returns.
2. JVMTI callback. Similarly, local references will live until the callback returns.
3. [GetEnv](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#GetEnv) call.

   3.1. From `JNI_OnLoad`, `Agent_OnLoad`, `Agent_OnAttach` entries. Local references created inside these entries are valid until the return from the entry.

   3.2. From a thread attached by [AttachCurrentThread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#AttachCurrentThread) function. References will be alive until [DetachCurrentThread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#detaching_from_the_vm) is called.

All local references are [only valid in the thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#global_and_local_references) in which they are created. The native code must not pass local references from one thread to another.

Note that JVM guarantees<sup>[1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#EnsureLocalCapacity),[2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#refs)</sup> that 16 local references can be created in one frame. If you need more local refs, you have to manage them explicitly with [PushLocalFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#PushLocalFrame) / [PopLocalFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#PopLocalFrame) JNI functions.

`jclass`, `jthread`, `jstring`, `jarray` etc. are all [JNI references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#reference_types) like `jobject`. They also need to be managed, unlike `jmethodID` and `jfieldID` which are not JNI references.